# Proof that this function is not identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc. Define $u : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $u(z) = Im (\frac{1-z}{1+z})^2$ show that $u(z)$ is not identically zero. My attempt: if $u(z)$ were identically zero then $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ would be real valued. But $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ is a fractional linear transformation and so has an inverse and both it and its inverse are holomorphic. This implies that both it and its inverse are continuous, which would mean that the open unit disc is homeomorphic to some subset of the real line, which is impossible. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> if $u(z)$ were identically zero then $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ would be real valued

which is not completely correct: If $u(z)$ were identically zero then $\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^2$ would be real valued, which means that $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ takes only purely real or purely imaginary values.

But you can argue as follows: A real-valued holomorphic function is necessarily *constant.*  But $ \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^2$ is not constant in the unit disk.

Comment: Ah thanks. Could I use my argument still because a subset of the real line union a subset of the imaginary line cannot be homeomorphic to the open unit disc?

Comment: @Aphyd: Yes, you could the “open mapping theorem”: A non-constant holomorphic function maps open sets to open sets. But a subset of  the union of the real  and imaginary axis is not an open set.

Comment: Great thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$U(x,y)=\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^2,$$ take $z=x+iy, x,y \ne 0$, then
$$U(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^2-y^2+2i(x-1)y}{(x+1)^2-y^2+2i(x+1)y}$$
Finally, its imaginary part (say $u(x,y)$) can never be zero as $y \ne 0$

Comment: Ya I thought of this but wanted to do it without just calculating, is my proof wrong in some way?

Comment: Oh! it displays your awareness but sorry the question is more elementary and simple.